# Is there a way for double inverted commas to override a separator using sqlite

Tags: import, sqlite, separator

This is my sqlite code:

```
create table A(A1 text, A2 text);
.separator ","
import outData.csv A
```

I get an error statement as so:

```
outData.csv Line 4: expected 2 columns of data but found 4
```

This is what Line 4 looks like:

```
Hallieo,"h, a, and ll"
```

I understand why the error message comes up. But I was wondering if anyone can suggest a way for me to store - "h, a, and ll" as one record. Thus being able to override the separator command in the presence of a double inverted comma.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tokenizer, which is what splits a line up into individual fields, in the sqlite3 console program is straightforward and not up to this challenge.

You will have to write your own program to read the file line by line, tokenize each line, and store into the database.  An entertaining challenge that will occupy a day if you really know your programming language.

Myself, I use C++ and for this sort of thing would use boost::tokenizer.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I love brain-teasers as these. I use python for easy scripting. I might try this as a side-assignment. Although for now, there was just that one line in the file that was interfering, so I directly went in and modified the line. I know not the best programmers approach, but hey something's gotta give. :)